# How to adapt a user interface to an OWL ontology

Tags: html, interface, semantics, ontology, owl

For example consider the ontology describes a family tree

I would want to represent this graphically on the web. For instance, the class 'mother' would have the image of a woman and the class 'father' would have that of a man.

The relationship such as childOf would be represented by a green arrow, whereas parentOf arrow would be in the opposite direction but represented by a red arrow.

The user should be able to navigate the tree ontology presented by this graphical model.

Could anybody advise on any resources to study. I have been advised to use HTML5, but am unsure of how to go about it. So basically, the main problem is how to represent the ontology graphically.

Any answer I would appreciate, many thanks.

Comment: update - i managed to find using scalable vector graphics may a good starting point for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using graph viz - http://graphviz.org/content/kennedyanc , this example is rather similar to your case. What you are tryign to draw is a directed acyclic graph - googling for libraries shoudl give you more similar tools - hopefully its not necessary to write it yourself

Comment: thank you so much!! :D first person to help me and it's great help

Comment: i've done a bit more research now and this is exactly what I wanted to do, you've saved me so much time and effort

Comment: no worries at all - delighted I could help. Also answers.semanticweb.com is another great resource for semweb Q+A if you're getting into that area.